Terraform Nested loop for.each example
I'm attempting to create nested loops to iterate over each environment (dev, qa, uat) and build target group attachments for the target IPs associated with each environment.
Here's what I have so far:
variable "qlink_target_ids" {
  type    = map(list(string))
  default = {
    dev = ["10.10.10.10", "10.10.10.20"]
    qa  = ["10.100.10.101"]
    uat = ["10.105.10.106", "10.10.10.217", "10.100.10.201"]
  }
}

variable "environments" {
  type    = set(string)
  default = ["dev", "qa", "uat"]
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "nlb_to_tg_qlink_attachments" {
  for_each           = { for env in var.environments : env => var.qlink_target_ids[env][0] }
  target_group_arn  = aws_lb_target_group.nlb_qlink_target_groups[each.key].arn
  target_id         = each.value
  availability_zone = "all"
  port              = 10001
}

However, I'm encountering an issue where it only assigns the first IP from target_ids, and it doesn't iterate over the loop to handle all IPs in target_ids for each environment. The target_id attribute only accepts a string and not a list, which complicates the situation.
I've attempted a few approaches to address this issue, including using the dynamic block to iterate over each IP, but I'm running into errors indicating that the target_id attribute is required.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Try#1
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "nlb_to_tg_qlink_attachments" {
  for_each = {
    for env, ids in var.qlink_target_ids : env => ids
  }

  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.nlb_qlink_target_groups[each.key].arn

  dynamic "attachment" {
    for_each = each.value

    content {
      target_id         = attachment.value
      availability_zone = "all"
      port              = 10001
    }
  }
}


Error: Required attribute "target_id" not specified: An attribute named "target_id" is required hereTerraform
Unexpected block: Blocks of type "dynamic" are not expected hereTerraform

Try#2
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "nlb_to_tg_postsql_attachments" {
  for_each = {
    for env, ids in var.postsql_target_ids : env => ids
  }

  target_group_arn  = aws_lb_target_group.nlb_postsql_target_groups[each.key].arn
  availability_zone = "all"
  port              = 10001

  dynamic "target_id" {
    for_each = each.value
    content {
      target_id = target_id.value
    }
  }
}


Error: Required attribute "target_id" not specified: An attribute named "target_id" is required here

try#3
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "nlb_to_tg_qlink_attachments" {
  for_each = {
    for env, ids in var.qlink_target_ids : env => ids
  }

  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.nlb_qlink_target_groups[each.key].arn

  dynamic "attachment" {
    for_each = each.value

    content {
      target_id         = attachment.value
      availability_zone = "all"
      port              = 10001
    }
  }
}


Error: Required attribute "target_id" not specified: An attribute named "target_id" is required here

Try#4
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "nlb_to_tg_postsql_attachments" {
  for_each = {
    for env, ids in var.postsql_target_ids : env => ids
  }

  target_group_arn  = aws_lb_target_group.nlb_postsql_target_groups[each.key].arn
  target_id         = each.value
  availability_zone = "all"
  port              = 5432
}


Error:╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on nlb.tf line 149, in resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "nlb_to_tg_postsql_attachments":
│  149:   target_id         = each.value
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is list of string with 2 elements
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "target_id": string required.


"but not working"  is not specific. What EXACTLY is happening? Any errors?

Updated my comment for clear understanding.


First, I find it weird that you are processing all the environments simultaneously. Ideally, you shall run terraform plan and apply for one environment at a time. For example, terraform plan -var 'environment=dev' and you can modify the resource block similar to the following

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "nlb_to_tg_qlink_attachments" {
  count             = length(lookup(var.qlink_target_ids, var.environment))
  target_group_arn  = aws_lb_target_group.nlb_qlink_target_groups[var.environment].arn
  target_id         = element(lookup(var.qlink_target_ids, var.environment), count.index)
  availability_zone = "all"
  port              = 10001
}


Second, to answer your original query, one way is to reverse the map and run for_each over it. Here is the code:

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "nlb_to_tg_qlink_attachments" {
  for_each          = merge([
    for env, ips in var.qlink_target_ids : {
      for ip in ips : ip => env
    }
  ]...)
  target_group_arn  = aws_lb_target_group.nlb_qlink_target_groups[each.value].arn
  target_id         = each.key
  availability_zone = "all"
  port              = 10001
}

The expression in the for_each loop will produce a map like
{
  "10.10.10.10"   = "dev"
  "10.10.10.20"   = "dev"
  "10.100.10.101" = "qa"
  .....
  .....
}


Thank yor for your prompt response. Yes, I am running a centralized (overlay) network for all qa, dev, uat with different accounts behind it. I am very new to terraform environment. I can write basic code but having issues with loops and all.
│ Error
│  157:   for_each          = merge([
│  158:     for env, ips in var.qlink_target_ids : {
│  159:       for ip in ips : ip => env
│  160:     }
│  161:   ])
while calling merge(maps...)
var.qlink_target_ids is map of list of string with 3 elements
Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got "tuple".


Try using any recent release of the terraform version
